# How to access a raspberry pi localhost from a linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, localhost, raspbian

I set up a php file in my raspberry pi so that I can access some files on it from my local network.

Within raspbian, it works well in any browser using `localhost/test`. I tested it also in a Windows and a Mac computer in the same network, using `my.local.ip.address/test` in my browsers and it also worked fine.

Now here is the problem: in my linux computer, it does not work. It simply says that "the site cannot be reached". I already tried disabling the firewall (UFW) but it doesn't change anything.

I also tried several browsers in linux and the result is the same.

I think I am overseeing something obvious but I cannot see it.

Could someone give me a pointer on what might be wrong?

**ifconfig -a output (Linux machine)**

[image]

**ifconfig -a output (Raspberry Pi machine)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your Ubuntu machine is not in the same network. You can try theses steps to confirm :

**Ping**

Go on your ubuntu machine and type :

```
ping <rasp.pi.local.ip.address>
```

Go on your Raspberry Pi and type :

```
ping <ubuntu.local.ip.address>
```

If the ping request do not succeed your machines are probably in different networks. Your can use this command to watch the path used by packets between your ubuntu machine and your Raspberry Pi :

```
traceroute <rasp.pi.local.ip.address>
```

**Change network card settings**

Before this step, check if your are able to connect your machines togather (switch, router, vlan...).

```
ifconfig <interface> down    
ifconfig <interface> <ip.network> netmask <netmask.network>
ifconfig <interface> up
```

After completing theses steps try to ping again and access to your website.

Comment: Indeed I cannot ping my Pi device. This is odd as we should be in the same network. <code>arp-scan</code> also doesn't show it there. The only thing I can imagine is that my route is dual-channel and by chance my linux machine is the only one in a different channel. Could it be? And is there a way to force it to the same channel?

Comment: @beakman : Can you ping other machine on your network (windows / mac) with your Ubuntu ?

Also, can you edit your previous post with the command : `ifconfig -a` on your Raspberry and Ubuntu ?

Comment: I can ping every other computer in the network, but the raspberry. On the other computers, I can ping everyone, but this linux. It simply seems like this computer is locked out, but I don't see how or why. I will edit the post now.

Comment: Here it is. Sorry for the delay. I didnt have access to it at that time.

Comment: Are you sure there is no IP conflict with your Ubuntu and any other machine on your network ? For exemple, two machine with the same IP address.

Comment: There is no reason to believe so. I have in total 6 machines in the network, I can see all of them in the other computers and they all ping correctly. Also if there would be a conflict, my mac or windows wouldn't connect to the Pi, but it does. I really am running out of ideas on what might be the issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, your Raspberry Pi machine and your Ubuntu machine are cannected via wifi ?
It's possible to make a test with a cable connection ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. They are connected via wifi indeed. I connected them with a cable and still it is not possible to ping each other.